# Rearranging a datatable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm importing an excel file into a datatable (dtImport) and rearranging that data into another datatable (dtImportParsed).

Here's what that datatable (dtImport) looks like when I first import it.
[image]

And this is how I'm trying to rearrange that datatable (dtImportParsed):
[image]

I'm currently accomplishing this by using some nested for loops, but this takes a very long time. For example, a sheet with 36 columns and 4,000 rows takes about 30-40 minutes to complete. Is there an alternative method of accomplishing this that would speed things up?
Here's my code:

```
for (int c = 2; c < dtImport.Columns.Count; c++) //for each date column
            {
                for (int r = 1; r < dtImport.Rows.Count; r++)
                {
                    if (dtImportParsed.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        DataRow dataRowImport = dtImportParsed.NewRow();
                        dataRowImport["Date"] = dtImport.Columns[c].ColumnName.ToString().Trim();
                        dataRowImport["account_id"] = dtImport.Rows[r]["account_id"].ToString().Trim();
                        dataRowImport[dtImport.Rows[r]["Event Name"].ToString().Trim()] = dtImport.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim();
                        dtImportParsed.Rows.Add(dataRowImport);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dtImportParsed.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (dtImportParsed.Rows[i]["account_id"].ToString() == dtImport.Rows[r]["account_id"].ToString())
                            {
                                if (dtImportParsed.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString() == dtImport.Columns[c].ColumnName.ToString())
                                {
                                    dtImportParsed.Rows[i][dtImport.Rows[r]["Event Name"].ToString().Trim()] = dtImport.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (i == dtImportParsed.Rows.Count - 1)
                            {
                                DataRow dataRowImport = dtImportParsed.NewRow();
                                dataRowImport["Date"] = dtImport.Columns[c].ColumnName.ToString().Trim();
                                dataRowImport["account_id"] = dtImport.Rows[r]["account_id"].ToString().Trim();
                                dataRowImport[dtImport.Rows[r]["Event Name"].ToString().Trim()] = dtImport.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim();
                                dtImportParsed.Rows.Add(dataRowImport);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but solves the problem.  I'm not certain how you're doing the import, but some Excel libraries will provide access to the Excel functionality as you work with the file. As such, can you issue the pivot command to the Excel file before extracting the data?  Another alternative would be to move to a database, and use SQL Pivot command.

Comment: Hi, the pivot in excel doesn't rotate the table in the same way that I need it unfortunately :(. Also, no access to a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you use to generate your expected result is too expensive! It will execute in order `(c x r x i)` where `i > r` because empty fields are injected in the final table; Actually it is an **O(n<sup>3</sup>)** algorithm! Also you preform it on `DataTable`s via iterating `DataRow`s that probably are not efficient for your requirement.

If your source data-set **is not large** (as you mentioned) and you **have not memory restriction**, I propose you to arrange expected data-set **in memory** using **index-based** data structures. Something like this:

```
var arrangeDragon = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
```

The dragon enters! And eats the inner `for`.

```
for (int c = 2; c < dtImport.Columns.Count; c++) //for each date column
{
    for (int r = 1; r < dtImport.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        // ...

        // instead of:     for (int i = 0; i < dtImportParsed.Rows.Count; i++) ...
        string date = dtImport.Columns[c].ColumnName.ToString().Trim();
        string accountId = dtImport.Rows[r]["account_id"].ToString();
        string eventName = dtImport.Rows [r]["Event Name"].ToString().Trim();

        if (!arrangeDragon.ContainsKey(date))
            arrangeDragon.Add(date, new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>());

        if (!arrangeDragon[date].ContainsKey(accountId))
            arrangeDragon[date][accountId] = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (!arrangeDragon[date][accountId].ContainsKey(eventName))
            arrangeDragon[date][accountId][eventName] = dtImport.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim();

        // ...
    }
}
```

These checks will execute in O(1) instead of O(i), so total overhead will decrease to **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** that is the nature of iterating table :)

Also retrieve order is O(1):

```
string data_field = arrangeDragon["1/1/2022"]["account1"]["Event1"];
Assert.AreEqual(data_field, "42");
```

Now you can iterate nested `Dictionary`s once and build the `dtImportParsed`.

If your data-set is large or host memory is low, you need other solutions that is not your problem as mentioned ;)

Good luck